# aws mysql connection issue for azure site

Tags: mysql, azure, amazon-web-services

I cant seem to find an answer to my issue.

I made a quick little website with .net and published it on azure.
when I test it I can query my aws mysql db just fine however after publishing I am getting.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open. at 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception 
exception) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex) at 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex) at 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState() at 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at 
TaskiiLink._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
C:\............\Default.aspx.cs:line 39
```

line 39: MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

my connection string is :

```
 <add name="dbconn" connectionString="user id=NAME;Password=PASS;persistsecurityinfo=true;server=AWSENDPOINT;Port=3306;database=DB;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

page load code

```
 if(Request["type"] == "1")
   {
     string sql = "checkDB";
     conn.Open();
     using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql))
      {         
       command.Connection = conn;
       try
        {
          MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
          if (!reader.Read())
             {
               Response.Write("false");
             } else
             {
               Response.Write("true");
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself,

AWS security group was only allowing my local host ip as an inbound.

found my web apps outbound ip in the property settings in azure portal.

helpful links if anyone has the same issue.

AWS issue

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=176030

azure info

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls

issue I had when adding the ip solution.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=158994

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the connection object.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
```